# object disappears when applied remesh

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I have an object with the following node network, When I add the remesh modifier with the block mode the mesh dissapears, why is this happening

[image]

Comment: Try doing the dispacement with a modifier instead of using nodes.

Comment: The reason is simple: the polygons are displaced at render time (post process) so there is nothing to operate on. If you'd like to remesh your terrain, you would have to displace the actual mesh eg. using a displace modifier in the first place.